# How to distinguish the direction of important features from xgboost or random forest?

Tags: nlp, random-forest, xgboost, sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I'm now working on binary text classification problem (like sentiment analysis), and it's trivial to pull out top important features of xgboost or random forest just by `feature_importances_`

Suppose we have two labelling 1 and 0 for this classification problem. Then there's any way to print out the direction of the features (positive or negative)? Say, word feature A has an enrichment or high tfidf with labelling 1.

Certainly I could pull out the tfidf column of this specific word feature, and correlate with the labelling with pearson coefficient, and the +/- of coefficient would indicate the direction, right? Any other more elegant way for this or xgboost and random forest has built-in such functions. (I didn't find)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't exactly what you're asking for, but I usually use [Lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) to do this. I like how it works even if I switch models.

Comment: Thanks actually I've read both TreeInterpreter and Lime and seems the feature importance list generated is for "each test". While my purpose is to give an overall list,  so I could simply sum up the importance weight for each test? Thx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lime (which Sam H suggested), [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) is also an option here.